# NSMutableArray overwrites last object

Tags: objective-c

I had initialized both nsmutablearray and nsmutable dictinay outside the loop than also its overwriting last object to all array

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictNew=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *newArr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//dictNew=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"firstName"] objectAtIndex:0] count]; i++)
{
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"firstName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"firstName"]:
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"lastName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"lastName"];
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"phones"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"phones"];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictNew);
    [newArr addObject:dictNew];
    NSLog(@"newarr %@",newArr);
}
```

Comment: Please post the output of `NSLog()` and beautify your code (indention). Moreover the code would be better readable, if you assign a reference to the inner array to a reference variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reuse `dictNew` like that. You need a new instance for each iteration. As you have it, you end up adding the same dictionary to the array over and over.

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *newArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [[[contactsData valueForKey:@"firstName"] objectAtIndex:0] count]; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictNew=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"firstName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"firstName"]:
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"lastName"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"lastName"];
    [dictNew setObject:[[[contactsData valueForKey:@"phones"]objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"phones"];
    NSLog(@"%@",dictNew);
    [newArr addObject:dictNew];
    NSLog(@"newarr %@",newArr);
}
```

I also suggest some minor improvements and cleanup:

```
NSMutableArray *newArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *firstNames = [[contactsData valueForKey:@"firstName"] objectAtIndex:0];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < firstNames.count; i++) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dictNew = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dictNew[@"firstName"] = firstNames[i];
    dictNew[@"lastName"] = [[[contactsData valueForKey:@"lastName"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i];
    dictNew[@"phones"] = [[[contactsData valueForKey:@"phones"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"dictNew = %@", dictNew);
    [newArr addObject:dictNew];
}
NSLog(@"newArr = %@", newArr);
```